# Modifying a variable in the upper levels in Java

Tags: java, class, variables, inner-classes

I need to change a variable in the upper class from the nested (I guess it could be called this way, I am new to java, I searched it but couldn't find it)

The code:

```
public class mainClass {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      boolean variableToChange = false;
      Timer myTimer = new Timer();
      TimerTask myTimerTask= new TimerTask() {
         public void run() {
            if(variableToChange==false) {    //it can read the variable
               variableToChange = true;         //but it can't change it?! 
                                                //it triggers and error here
            }
         }
      };
      myTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(myTimerTask, 0, 100);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access, but *cannot* change `variableToChange` since it's inside an anonymous inner-class and declared outside it.

From [JLS 8.1.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/#8.1.3):

> Any local variable, formal method parameter or exception handler parameter used but not declared in an inner class must be declared final. Any local variable, used but not declared in an inner class must be definitely assigned before the body of the inner class.

Variables declared outside an anonymous inner-class are considered `final` inside it.
You are probably using Java 8 where where `final` can be implicit.

A "dirty" workaround (which isn't recommended due to synchronization issues, but works) is to declare:

```
final boolean[] variableToChange = new boolean[1];
```

And then you will be able to change it inside:

```
variableToChange[0] = true;
```

Comment: @JohnRW, no because you cannot change the value inside the Boolean (the big type) without reassigning it. And, you cannot do that since you declared it as `final`.

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution:

```
package com.example;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class mainClass {

    public static class MyBoolean {
        public boolean value;
    };

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      final MyBoolean variableToChange = new MyBoolean();
      Timer myTimer = new Timer();
      TimerTask myTimerTask= new TimerTask() {
         public void run() {
            if(variableToChange.value==false) {    //it can read the variable
                variableToChange.value = true;         //but it can't change it?! 
                                                //it triggers and error here
            }
         }
      };
      myTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(myTimerTask, 0, 100);
   }
}
```

You have to declare variableToChange as final, to allow its modification in inner class. You cannot modify it, since you declare as final variable. So you need to encapsulate it in a object, and then modify its attributes.

Comment: I understand this is the way to do it, but I am too new to Java, I just can't choice the correct label static, final, public private etc. it always throws me some error with those labels.

Comment: Probably you remove static from MyBoolean definition. I compile this code before post it, it works.

Comment: Ok! Thanks! I will try it again.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
public static boolean variableToChange = false;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

              Timer myTimer = new Timer();
              TimerTask myTimerTask= new TimerTask() {
                 public void run() {
                    if(mainClass .variableToChange==false) {    //it can read the variable
                        mainClass .variableToChange = true;         //but it can't change it?! 
                                                        //it triggers and error here
                    }
                 }
              };
              myTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(myTimerTask, 0, 100);
           }
```

variable must be in class, not in method because you want to change it from the other object.